# How to get the change / delta for start and end values in onMove or onMoving function with vis.js timeline

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js, vis-timeline

I have been using onMoving event to trace the changing values of start and end.

How can I find the delta between previous and current values of start and end ?

```
onMoving: function(item, callback) {

    if (item.start < options.min) item.start = options.min;

    if (item.video_start == 0 && item.segment_start < item.video_start) {
        item.segment_start = item.video_start;
    }

    if (item.video_end > 0 && item.segment_end > item.video_end) {
        item.segment_end = item.video_end;
    }

    callback(item);
    rearrange_timeline_min_max_value();
},
```

I can see the values with following event, however this is also needed in onMove and onMoving in order to finalize it callback(item) or callback(null).

```
timeline_items.on('*', function (event, properties) {
    console.log("Properties : " + JSON.stringify(properties));
});
```

How can I get the delta for start and end with onMoving ?

Comment: Which version of vis.js are you using?

Comment: version 7.5.0
 date    2021-11-06T19:14:36.014Z

Comment: @FrancescoVattiato, I am not sure if onMoving or any kind of events support this natively, as the only function arguments consists of item and callback, that is it.

Comment: I am not sure if this might help. I also had the use case to implement call back based on original item values like how much i can drag or not. what i did was, while preparing timeline item, i created the array of items and stored in diff variable. whenever i used to get call inside onMove, I used to fetch whole object from that array, finding using item.id. and using the object and comparing it with item data and proceeding accordingly

Comment: @Vivek Pandita, That is the exact situation, "to decide how much you can drag". There is no applicable way to see within the current state of onMoving function with two arguments (item, callback) as far as I can see. Is this correct ?

Comment: What about fething the data in onMove function as below : 

        prev_item_state = timeline_items.get({
            fields: ['id', 'start', 'end'],//we can specify one or more fields
            filter: function (prev_item) {
                console.log("filter : " + item.id + " - " + prev_item.id);
                return prev_item.id == item.id;
            }
        })[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item is not updated in the items DataSet until the callback function is called by `onMove`. You can therefore fetch the existing item from the DataSet within the `onMove` and `onMoving` functions and use the original values in your logic.

```js
onMoving: function(item, callback){
  // Fetch the current item from the DataSet
  let currentItem = items.get(item.id);
  ...
```

Example is included into the post below and also at https://jsfiddle.net/2gmj8uec/. The example just logs the old start / end times along with the updated ones. When moving the 'From' time doesn't change until a moved event has fired to update the DataSet.

```js
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById("visualization");

// Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, content: "item 1", start: new Date(2021, 11, 20) },
  { id: 2, content: "item 2", start: new Date(2021, 11, 14) },
  { id: 3, content: "item 3", start: new Date(2021, 11, 18) },
  { id: 4, content: "item 4", start: new Date(2021, 11, 16), end: new Date(2021, 11, 19) },
  { id: 5, content: "item 5", start: new Date(2021, 11, 25) },
  { id: 6, content: "item 6", start: new Date(2021, 11, 27), type: "point" },
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
  editable: true,
  onMoving: function(item, callback){
    // Fetch the current item from the DataSet
    let currentItem = items.get(item.id);

    // Log the changes
    console.log("Moving Start - From:", currentItem.start.toISOString(), "To:", item.start.toISOString());
    if(item.end){
      console.log("Moving End - From:", currentItem.end.toISOString(), "To:", item.end.toISOString());
    }
    
    // Return the item, updated if needed
    callback(item);
  },
  onMove: function(item, callback){
    // Fetch the current item from the DataSet
    let currentItem = items.get(item.id);
  
    // Log the changes
    console.log("Moved Start - From:", currentItem.start.toISOString(), "To:", item.start.toISOString());
    if(item.end){
      console.log("Moved End - From:", currentItem.end.toISOString(), "To:", item.end.toISOString());
    }
    
    // Return the item, updated if needed
    // This will result in the items DataSet being updated
    callback(item);
  },
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Restrict height of console in stackoverflow snippet */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/styles/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="visualization"></div>
```